# ¿Cómo incluir un activador instalable en una función de google-apps-script?

Tags: ubuntu, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-chrome

Tengo la siguiente función creada en google-apps-script. En versiones muy iniciales del script, llegué a instalar un activador, pero luego lo quité para evitar las notificaciones de correo de gmail (dado que la función contenía errores). Ahora parece que la función está bien, pero no me deja instalar un activador y me da el siguiente error:

> Se ha producido un error inesperado ignorar"

pero no me dice qué tipo de error.

El navegador es Chrome y el OS Ubuntu 16.04

El script es:

```
function sheetTracker() { 

// Version 2.0

var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Obtenemos a que libro pertenece la celda que ha cambiado
var hoja = libro.getActiveSheet().getName(); // Obtenemos el nombre de la hoja en la que ha cambiado la celda
var lista = ['C61','C62','C63','C64','C65','C66']; // Celdas a monitorizar
var celda = libro.getActiveCell().getA1Notation(); // Obtenemos el nombre de la celda que ha cambiado
var valor = Number(libro.getActiveCell().getValue()); // El nuevo valor de la celda

// Si no se ha modificado una celda de la hoja de asistencia que toca salimos

if (hoja != "Mi hoja") return; 

if (lista.indexOf(celda) && valor > 0.25) { 
   var fila     = libro.getActiveCell().getRow();
   var columna  = libro.getActiveCell().getCol();
   var persona  = libro.getRange(fila,columna+2).getValue().toString();
   var email    = libro.getRange(fila,columna-2).getValue().toString();
   var yes      = libro.getRange(fila,columna+1).getValue();
   var justfied = libro.getRange(fila,columna-1).getValue();

   MailApp.sendEmail(email, subjecta, messagea); 
   MailApp.sendEmail(director, subjectd, messaged);


} else {
  return;
}
```

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste en modo de navegación incógnito con todas las extensiones inhabilitadas? ¿Cuántas hojas, celdas y datos tiene tu HCG? ¿Usas referencias abiertas en tus fórmulas? ¿Cuanto tiempo tarda en recualcularse tu HCG?

Comment: @Rubén He visto que tenia actualizaciones pendientes y precisamente eran de Chrome. Las he instalado y ahora si que me deja instalar el activador. En cualquier caso ¿Qué es "HCG"? No utilizo referencias abiertas, todas las celdas pertenecen a la misma hoja del libro, aunque el libro tiene muchas hojas distintas (por eso uso el primer "if")

Comment: _**H**_oja de _**C**_álculo de _**G**_oogle

Comment: Considera publicar lo que encontraste como solución, es decir como repuesta, seguramente le servirá a otros, ya vez, en mi comentario no pregunté si tenias o no actualizaciones pendientes :)